# Creating Ember View dynamically by setting templateName in Template

Tags: ember.js

I wish to load my View using a variable like this:

```
{{#if model.isLoaded }}
  Loaded: {{ model.template.slug }}
  {{ view App.DocumentView templateName="model.template.slug" }}
{{ else }}
  Loading…
{{/if}}
```

Is there a way to pass variable to a View like this? How could I otherwise load it when my model gets updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Binding to bind the template's name to your model's property.

```
{{#if model.isLoaded }}
  Loaded: {{ model.template.slug }}
  {{ view App.DocumentView templateNameBinding="model.template.slug" }}
{{ else }}
  Loading…
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! However, it's not working with belongsTo relationships, so I had to resort to mapping my attribute to model.templateSlug instead.

Comment: Turns out that if you sideload your models (http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) it will solve the problem I had before in my earlier comment.

Comment: Didn't work. To get it to work you need to add this to your view:

    templateNameChanged: function() {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('templateName')

Answer (score 0):

I created a library to help with this kind of issue, check at [github](https://github.com/juanjardim/ember-template-factory)